# How can I reference a static class in a map so I can call it?

Tags: java, static, mapping, invoke

So basically, the use case I'm trying to solve is that I have that needs to be processed, and that data is separated into several different types. I want to write a separate processor for each data type and then use a mapping to determine which processor to use and call it. Essentially, I want

```
private Map<String, EventProcessor> mapping =  new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Class>()
    .put("EventType1", EventType1Processor.class)
    .put("EventType2", EventType2Processor.class)
    .build();

public void processEvent(Event event){ 
    mapping.get(event.getType).process(event); 
}
```

Each processor is a static class and each EventTypeXProcessor extends off of the same class

I'm just not sure what's the right way to reference static classes in a map like that

Comment: Try a `Map<String, Consumer<Event>>` instead.

Comment: @LewBloch, the types mismatch, so it doesn't compile. The type in the declaration is EventProcessor, but the type in the map itself is a Class

The problem with DI is that all the event types are mixed together, and I get a stream of them to process, so I need to decide at runtime which processor to use. I can use DI to inject an instance of each class, but these are static classes, so it feels like a waste of resources to instantiate classes that don't need to be instantiated. The processors are already polymorphic

Comment: The type Class<T> does not have a method `process()`. No version of that map will work. You could use the class to generate an instance, but really why not just use polymorphism? It's already build into the language. EventProcessor processor = new Event1Processor(); processor.process(event); etc.